# Wrong output of bubble sort algorithm in Pascal

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, pascal

Recently I have been trying to create a bubble sort algorithm in Pascal language, however after the program is run, the output turned out to be only 0s and 1s. I wonder what have I done wrong.

```
program BubbleSort;

const n = 9;
var
    arr : array [0..n] of integer;
    num, a, b, i, j, temp : integer;
begin
    temp := 0;
    for a := 0 to n do
    begin
        writeln('Please enter the ', a, '-th element in the array:');
        readln(arr[a]);
    end;
    for i := 0 to (n - 1) do
    begin
        for j := 0 to (n - i - 1) do
        begin
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) then
            begin
                arr[j] := temp;
                arr[j] := arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] := temp;
            end;
        end;
    end;
    writeln('The sorted array is as follows:');
    for b := 0 to n do
    begin
        write(arr[b], ' ');
    end;
end.
```

Since I am familiar with C# and Java, I tried my best to declare the array to start from index 0, and that might be the cause of the problem. I have no idea.

Comment: `temp` is only assigned once with the value `0`. And `arr[j] := temp;` is in vain, because right after it you assign `arr[j]` to a new value, overriding the `0`. Effectively you set `temp` for no reason to `0`. Assigning values works from right to left: `variableToAssignValueTo := theNewValue`. Whoever upvoted this Q lacks basics at programming/Pascal. Compare with https://wiki.freepascal.org/Bubble_sort and https://wiki.freepascal.org/Basic_Pascal_Tutorial/Chapter_1/Assignment_and_Operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write

```
temp := arr[j];
```

instead of

```
arr[j] := temp;
```